# Understanding how the device list is read

Tags: r, graphics, device

I ran into a rather annoying issue with the list of open devices, trying to construct a function that saves a number of graphs for a list. Say we have following data :

```
Alist <- list(
  X1 = data.frame(X=rnorm(10),Y=1:10),
  X2 = data.frame(X=rnorm(10),Y=1:10),
  X3 = data.frame(X=rnorm(10),Y=1:10)
)
```

and following function :

```
myPlotFunc <- function(x,save=F){
    fnames <- paste(names(x),"pdf",sep=".")
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      if(save){
        pdf(fnames[i])
        on.exit(dev.off(),add=T)
      }
      plot(x[[i]])
    }
    fnames
  }
```

If I run `fnames <- myPlotFunc(Alist,save=T)`, everything behaves normally and I get 3 pdf files names `X1.pdf` to `X3.pdf`. That is, if there's no graphics window open. If there is, then one of the pdfs is not closed, and all subsequent plots are added to the pdf until I explicitly call `dev.off()` in the console. Like this :

```
plot(Alist[[1]])
fnames <- myPlotFunc(Alist,save=T)
myPlotFunc(Alist,save=F)

> dev.list()
pdf 
  4
```

If I add `on.exit({print(dev.cur());dev.off()},add=T)` , I get following output :

```
> fnames <- myPlotFunc(Alist,save=T)
pdf 
  5 
windows 
      2 
pdf 
  3
```

So apparently it takes the list from the bottom up again to close everything it meets. So if there is a graphics window open, that is the next "current" device. Meaning that the second-last opened pdf-connection will not be closed by dev.off() any more, as there will be one short in the `on.exit` call.

I got around it by changing my function to :

```
myPlotFunc <- function(x,save=F){
    fnames <- paste(names(x),"pdf",sep=".")
    devs <- NULL
    on.exit(for(i in devs) dev.off(i), add=T)
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
      if(save){
        pdf(fnames[i])
        devs <- c(devs,dev.cur())
      }
      plot(x[[i]])
    }
    fnames
  }
```

but this feels rather awkward. Is there something I'm missing here, or a better way of getting around this?

**disclaimer :**

**In case you're not aware, run `dev.off()` after running the third code block. You can clean up easily by running `unlink(fnames)` when you're done.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about making help function to do one plot:

```
myPlotFunc <- function(x, save=FALSE) {
    fnames <- paste(names(x), "pdf", sep=".")
    plot_one <- function(xx, fname, save=save) {
        if (save) {
            pdf(fname)
            on.exit(dev.off())
        }
        plot(xx)
    }
    for (i in 1:length(x)) plot_one(x[[i]], fnames[i], save)

    fnames
}
```

Comment: good suggestion, I didn't think about that. Seems cleaner than my solution.

Comment: +1 Good solution and cleanest one on offer thus far, with fewest side-effects for existing devices (none)!

Comment: Very cunning.  Best change `1:length(x)` to `seq_along(x)` to avoid problems when `x` has length 0.

Comment: @Richie Very good point. I was thinking of using `mapply` and change it to `if (length(x)) mapply(plot_one, x, fnames, save) else warning("x has 0 length")`.

Answer (score 1):

One drastic solution might be to use `graphics.off()` instead of trying to close devices your script opens. If this is just user code, then perhaps it doesn't matter if all graphics devics are closed upon exit?

Using this brutal approach seems to work:

```
myPlotFunc <- function(x,save = FALSE) {
    fnames <- paste(names(x),"pdf",sep=".")
    if(save)
        on.exit(graphics.off(),add = TRUE)
    for(i in 1:length(x)) {
      if(save) {
        pdf(fnames[i])
      }
      plot(x[[i]])
    }
    fnames
  }
```

An alternative is just to list all devices when `on.exit()` gets called, select out the `pdf` ones and close them. This function implements this and seems to have the desired behaviour.

```
myPlotFunc2 <- function(x,save = FALSE) {
    fnames <- paste(names(x), "pdf", sep=".")
    if(save) {
        on.exit(foo <- lapply(dev.list()[grepl("pdf", names(dev.list()))], 
                              dev.off),
                add = TRUE)
    }
    for(i in 1:length(x)) {
      if(save) {
        pdf(fnames[i])
      }
      plot(x[[i]])
    }
    fnames
  }
```

It seems the lowest numbered device is the one that R activates after a call to `dev.off()`, and that will be the on-screen device in the setting you describe, and hence the behaviour your report.

Comment: thx for the suggestions. I don't really understand though why the result of the `lapply` should be assigned to `foo` in the `on.exit` call

Comment: My ignorance of what happens if something is printed during an `on.exit()` call. I basically did this to stop the device names closed being printed at the end of the script. That is all it is doing, as `foo` is discarded as soon as `on.exit()` is done.